# Shared Drives disappearing in webui

Tags: google-drive-api

It seems that shared drives rendered in the drive webui disappears at random.  The behavior is reproducible on our demo/test site through the following procedures:

- Shared Drives created by our application through [www.googleapis.com](http://www.googleapis.com) are disappearing in Google Drive webui but are viewable via the API with useDomainAccess = true.
- Sometimes a newly created share drive return notFound by the API when queried for via driveId.
- Shared Drives created directly through Drive webui also disappear from the list but are viewable through the API.

Some questions arise from these behaviors:

1. Is there a potential bug in the Drive webui that prevents shared drives from being rendered?  I traced the query to the API using Fiddler and nothing seems of interest.  Without diving into the code that renders the page, I'm not sure why this is happening.
2. Are there any propagation/permissions issues when creating a shared drive via the API then immediately querying the API for it?  Our applications behavior is such that if a shared drive does not exist, it will create one then it will begin uploading files to it.  It seems that occasionally the application will create the shared drive, then on the subsequent get call it will fail with 'notFound', then create a duplicate named shared drive.  The get call does send the correct driveId so I would expect the get call should succeed.

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code and describe any issues you are having with your solution.

Comment: Do they appear later (delayed propagation issue)? Do they reappear after disappearing? Are they always viewable via the API after the initial propagation? How long does it take to propagate? What code could I use to reproduce the issue? Its possible its a bug, have you checked https://issuetracker.google.com/ ?